# unable to pass performance at Codility GenomicRangeQuery test

Tags: java, performance

Could you please check the code and let me know what I have to do to increase performance ? This performance issue makes me mad at Codility. Here is the question and my code below.

Thank you for your helps from now on .

Test :

ask description
A DNA sequence can be represented as a string consisting of the letters A, C, G and T, which correspond to the types of successive nucleotides in the sequence. Each nucleotide has an impact factor, which is an integer. Nucleotides of types A, C, G and T have impact factors of 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively. You are going to answer several queries of the form: What is the minimal impact factor of nucleotides contained in a particular part of the given DNA sequence?

The DNA sequence is given as a non-empty string S = S[0]S[1]...S[N-1] consisting of N characters. There are M queries, which are given in non-empty arrays P and Q, each consisting of M integers. The K-th query (0 ≤ K < M) requires you to find the minimal impact factor of nucleotides contained in the DNA sequence between positions P[K] and Q[K] (inclusive).

For example, consider string S = CAGCCTA and arrays P, Q such that:

```
P[0] = 2    Q[0] = 4
P[1] = 5    Q[1] = 5
P[2] = 0    Q[2] = 6
```

The answers to these M = 3 queries are as follows:

The part of the DNA between positions 2 and 4 contains nucleotides G and C (twice), whose impact factors are 3 and 2 respectively, so the answer is 2.
The part between positions 5 and 5 contains a single nucleotide T, whose impact factor is 4, so the answer is 4.
The part between positions 0 and 6 (the whole string) contains all nucleotides, in particular nucleotide A whose impact factor is 1, so the answer is 1.
Write a function:

class Solution { public int[] solution(String S, int[] P, int[] Q); }

that, given a non-empty string S consisting of N characters and two non-empty arrays P and Q consisting of M integers, returns an array consisting of M integers specifying the consecutive answers to all queries.

Result array should be returned as an array of integers.

For example, given the string S = CAGCCTA and arrays P, Q such that:

```
P[0] = 2    Q[0] = 4
P[1] = 5    Q[1] = 5
P[2] = 0    Q[2] = 6
```

the function should return the values [2, 4, 1], as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
M is an integer within the range [1..50,000];
each element of arrays P, Q is an integer within the range [0..N − 1];
P[K] ≤ Q[K], where 0 ≤ K < M;
string S consists only of upper-case English letters A, C, G, T.

My Solution:

```
  public static int[] solution(String S, int[] firstArray, int[] secondArray) {
    String subStr="";
    int[] result = new int[firstArray.length];
    for(int i=0; i < firstArray.length; i++)  {
        subStr = S.substring(firstArray[i], secondArray[i] + 1);
        if(subStr.contains("A")) { result[i] = 1; }
        else if(subStr.contains("C")){ result[i] = 2; }
        else if(subStr.contains("G")){ result[i] = 3;
        } else if(subStr.contains("T")){ result[i] = 4;
        }
    }
```

return result;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is of complexity O(M*N).
Outer loop: for(int i=0; i < firstArray.length; i++) (Complexity M)
Inner loop: Assess list S of N size to construct subStr (Complexity is MxN at this point)
Same Inner loop: Check each subStr if it contains each of the 4 letters (Complexity is MxN at this point)

To improve performance, your solution needs to do away with the inner loop. One way to do that is to convert S into a form that we can access the relevant values directly rather than iterating through (i.e. constructing subStr).

One way to convert S into something relevant that is accessible directly is to store the last observable position for each of the 4 nucleotide (A/C/G/T) at each position in the sequence.

For example, if S = "CGGT", we can convert it into, with -1 referring to "not yet observed":

```
Idx A, C, G, T  
0  [-1, 0,-1,-1]  
1  [-1, 0, 1,-1]  
2  [-1, 0, 2,-1]  
3  [-1, 0, 2, 3]
```

With this matrix, we can now directly access it to get the relevant values. In this case, if we are trying to get the relevant values for subStr "GG", i.e. P[0] = 1 and Q[0] = 2,
then we just need to access index 2. In this case, [-1, 0, 2, -1] tells us that only G was last observed after index 1, hence, the minimum impact is the mapping of G to it's impact factor.

Building the matrix is of complexity O(N). Iterating through P and Q is of complexity O(M). Since there are no nested loops, the overall complexity is O(N+M).

Below is a snippet of the implementation in Python:

```
def solution(S,P,Q):
    l = len(S)    
    lastSeen = [[-1,-1,-1,-1] for x in range(l)]
    for x in range(len(S)):
        for i,j in enumerate(list("ACGT")):
            if S[x] == j:
                lastSeen[x][i] = x
            elif x>0: 
                lastSeen[x][i] = lastSeen[x-1][i]

    res = []
    for x in range(len(P)):
        startIdx = P[x]
        relevantLastSeen = lastSeen[Q[x]]
        res.append((min([i+1 for i,x in enumerate(relevantLastSeen) if x>=startIdx])))

    return res
```